# PhpStorm Deployment Settings

Tags: deployment, ide, project, web-deployment, phpstorm

please tell me how to synchronize projects in PHPStorm. 
For example, I edited the project at work, when I come I need to sync it with a computer at home.

Or I do not know if I edited the project or not, but I need to sync with what is now on FTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tools | Deployment | Sync with Deployed...`

- http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deployments+in+PhpStorm
- http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/03/webinar-recording-deployment-with-phpstorm/